# Is there a measure or precedure that could decide if an input signal actually correspond to an EEG signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a lot of mixed files, and from those files I would like to keep those that correspond to EEG recordings.

The problem is that some EEG files are supposed to be recorded with 2, 4, 5 and 6 channels, and that there also is other data (of unknown type) that also have the same amount of channels (I already filtered those that don't have these amount of channels). And of course, there are thousands of files, so manual inspection isn't really an option.

So, is there some kind of metric or algorithm that helps me to differentiate non-EEG signal from EEG ones? With MATLAB if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might first try comparing statistics such as mean, std and kurtosis of each channel relative to known good channels.  Since you have lots of files, you would probably want to the sample possible matches in a few places (e.g., compare seconds 1-3 and say 7-9) and then get a probability of match.  Interesting question!

Comment: this give me and idea, I could train a svm or a ann to identify eeg....

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a MATLAB question, but...

What is (potentially) in the other recordings? Perhaps it is easier to filter them out than it is to identify EEG specifically.

I don't know of any metric or algorithm that can identify EEG recordings. One problem is that EEG recordings often contain artefacts to varying degrees such as muscle activity, line noise, and any other electromagnetic interference in the room that make the recording nonspecific to cortical activity.

The frequency spectrum may be one meaningful measure. Cortical activity usually tapers off in power towards, say, 40 Hz, and tends to have some peaks before. For example, depending on the placement of EEG electrodes and the task that was being performed, a peak in the alpha band (around 10 Hz) may be prominent. This is assuming there is little interference from artefacts.

Also the amplitude of the signal may be something to look at.

Perhaps you could take a number of measures and statistical properties (e.g. powers in different frequency bands, variance, drift/slope, amplitude, etc.), cluster them using e.g. [t-SNE](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/tsne.html), and, assuming you get clearly separable clusters, identify a few samples from each cluster by hand to figure out which is the EEG cluster.

Comment: analyzing eeg was part of my previous task, so i do have routines to filter artifacts and noise using ica and wavelet packet and wavelet transform. I don't really know what it is the other files (someone mixed everything....).....